# Using EF to store changes in database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have an application (dotnet core 1.1, C#) with 5 main entities, each stored in it's own table. I would like to have one master table who persists all the changes with the following columns:

- UserId (who made the change)
- DateModified
- Entity (which entity was changed)
- EntityId (id of the entity changed)
- NewValue
- OldValue

What is the best approach for this problem? Doing this all manually seems like an aweful lot of work.

Comment: You write a method for that and use that method. Logging seems like a good candidate for that, because you just specify custom output and you are done.

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#entity-framework-data-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Different ways you can achieve this . you can create logging framework using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) libraries.

Since you have very few entities my opinion is to create an [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#action-filters) and use that to log the details into the master table.

```
 public class LogAttribute : IActionFilter
 {
  public LogAttribute()
  {

  }

  public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {

  }

  public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
  {
    // save details to master table
  }
}
```